# Global media library returns array VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a project which contains a global VueJS file with child vuejs file depending on what page you are on.

I am trying to work out how to create a media manager which I can call multiple times per page and have it open up with a modal where I can either select an image or upload an image. I already know how to upload an image. What i need is once an image is selected or uploaded and a "Select" button is pressed it will close the modal and return an array back to the original element that called it and assigns to that element's variable.

Example would be:
I have a vuejs element called article_image with a variable called "article_image_data" and contains a button. When the button is created it opens the modal manager which you will need to select the image you want and press "Select" this modal then closes and returns an array which will be assigned to "article_image_data" and on the same page there may be a "category" section as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it simple, in your modal manager, listen to the change event on your file input.

```
<!-- ModalManager.vue -->
<template>
  <div class="modal">
    <input type="file" @change="$emit('selectedFiles', $event.target.files)">
  </div>
</template>
```

Then from your parent who implemented the modal manager, you can get the file list on the `selectedFiles` event.

```
<!-- ArticleImage.vue -->
<template>
  <ModalManager
    @selectedFiles="onSelectedFiles"
    v-if="modalOpen">
</template>
```

Easy now to deal with a [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/FileList)

```
export default {
  components: {
    ModalManager
  }
  data () {
    return {
      modalOpen: false,
      articleImageData: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSelectedFiles (fileList) {
      console.log('Received a FileList from ModalManager', fileList)
    }
  }
}
```

If you need a deeper component management for your modals, you either propagate your events from bottom to top with something like this:

```
<element @childEvent="$emit('childEvent')">
```

But the idea stays the same